# How can I add to the end of a font-family without overwriting it?

Tags: css

We have many sites with their own font families. I need to add a font to the end of the font family on every site. Is it possible to extend a font family?

```
p.test {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
p.test {
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

The above block sets the font-family to `Calibri`. I would like it to set the font-family to `Arial, Helvetica, Calibri`. Something like the below is what I'm looking for:

```
p.test {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
p.test {
    font-family: += Calibri;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly are you expecting the font to be, calibri or arial?

Comment: @epoch The fonts are probably a bad example because Arial is installed pretty much everywhere, but I'm wanting the font to be Calibri where none of the first three are installed and Arial where Arial is installed. Basically I want the font-family to be "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Calibri", as I said in the question. I'm not 'expecting' it to be any different to how it is. I'm expecting the font family to be overwritten and become 'Calibri'. But that's not what I want - I want to be able to extend the family instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply repeat all fonts, like so:

```
p.test {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

sans-serif is a generic expression that will use any available font on the users system without serifs, so it only makes sense to put it last.

UPDATE:

if the original style has an inherit at the end you may add fonts to the parent elements:

```
p.test {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, inherit;
}

div.p-parent {
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

If the last font in the line is sans-serif, thats what you're gonna get, if you choose not to overwrite it and repeat the other fonts.

Comment: I didn't know that about sans-serif, I'll take that font out of the example. However, I can't repeat all the fonts, the fonts are different from site to site. I need a way to append a font to the family.

Comment: hm, this is a strange use of font-family. i would try inheriting the font then:
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, inherit; And on the parent element use Calibri or whatever your fallback font may be. However inserting a font into a css style is not possible like that.

Comment: usually you'd have sans-serif or serif at the end of the line, so without overwriting your rule you dont have a chance to manipulate it, except it says inherit at the end

Answer (score -1):

Cant understand your question. 'sans-serif' will always fall back to the default sans-serif font on the user's machine. In your case, Calibri will always be ignored...

Comment: No, Calibri is not ignored. Calibiri becomes the font-family. But what I want is for Calibiri to be added to the end of the list of fonts comprising the family.